# Applying the getComputedStyle fix for IE to my code ... 'null' is null or not a object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, syntax, jquery-isotope, computed-style

Following to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850737/jquery-object-expected-in-internet-explorer-ie8-and) I had. I'm trying to apply the [following fix](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/getcomputedstyle-for-ie/) to get getComputedStyle to work with IE8 (and -) in the code I use for jQuery isotope. But I still get an error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I get 'null' is null or not a object error message with IE-Tester. The website is http://www.gablabelle.com/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var layoutI = 0;
        var $container = $("#stream");
        var $window = $(window);
//getComputedStyle fix for IE ?
        if (!window.getComputedStyle) {
            window.getComputedStyle = function(el, pseudo) {
                this.el = el;
                this.getPropertyValue = function(prop) {
                    var re = /(\-([a-z]){1})/g;
                    if (prop == 'float') prop = 'styleFloat';
                    if (re.test(prop)) {
                        prop = prop.replace(re, function () {
                            return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
                        });
                    }
                    return el.currentStyle[prop] ? el.currentStyle[prop] : null;
                }
                return this;
            }
        };
        function reLayout(){
// getComputedStyle is used here
            var mediaQueryId = getComputedStyle( document.body, ':after' ).getPropertyValue('content');
            // fix for firefox, remove double quotes
            var mediaQueryId = mediaQueryId.replace( /"/g, '' );
            // console.log( mediaQueryId );
            var windowSize = $window.width();
            var masonryOpts;
            // update sizing options 
            switch ( mediaQueryId ) {
                case 'bigger' :
                    masonryOpts = {
                        columnWidth: 270,
                        gutterWidth: 30
                    };
                break;
                case 'big' :
                    masonryOpts = {
                        columnWidth: 220,
                        gutterWidth: 20
                    };
                break;
                case 'medium' :
                    masonryOpts = {
                        columnWidth: 166,
                        gutterWidth: 20
                    };
                break;
                case 'small' :
                    masonryOpts = {
                        columnWidth: $container.width() / 2,
                        gutterWidth: 0
                    };  
                break;
            };
            $container.isotope({
                resizable: false, // disable resizing by default, we'll trigger it manually
                itemSelector : "article.post",
                animationEngine: "best-available",
                masonry: masonryOpts,
                onLayout: function() {
                //  console.log('layout!' + (layoutI++) )
                    forceLoad();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        html_height = $container.height();
                        $("#sidebar").height(html_height - masonryOpts.gutterWidth);
                    }, 500);
                }
            });
        };
        // start up isotope with default settings
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            reLayout();
            $window.smartresize( reLayout );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Nelson 's logic I decided to add the value I wanted to catch using jQuery instead of CSS to make sure it was in the DOM and can be manipulated.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var layoutI = 0;
    var $container = $("#stream");
    var $window = $(window);
    function windowSizeMe(){
        var windowSize = $window.width();
        if (windowSize > 1199) {
            $("#switch").attr("data-content", "bigger");
        } else if (windowSize < 1200 && windowSize > 979) {
            $("#switch").attr("data-content", "big");
        } else if (windowSize < 768) {
            $("#switch").attr("data-content", "small");
        } else {
            $("#switch").attr("data-content", "medium");
        };
    }; 
    function reLayout(){
        windowSizeMe(); 
        var mediaQueryId = $("#switch").attr("data-content");
        console.log(mediaQueryId);
        // fix for firefox, remove double quotes
        var mediaQueryId = mediaQueryId.replace( /"/g, '' );
        var masonryOpts;
        // update sizing options 
        switch ( mediaQueryId ) {
            case 'bigger' :
                masonryOpts = {
                    columnWidth: 270,
                    gutterWidth: 30
                };
            break;
            case 'big' :
                masonryOpts = {
                    columnWidth: 220,
                    gutterWidth: 20
                };
            break;
            case 'medium' :
                masonryOpts = {
                    columnWidth: 166,
                    gutterWidth: 20
                };
            break;
            case 'small' :
                masonryOpts = {
                    columnWidth: $container.width() / 2,
                    gutterWidth: 0
                };  
            break;
        };
        $container.isotope({
            resizable: false, // disable resizing by default, we'll trigger it manually
            itemSelector : "article.post",
            animationEngine: "best-available",
            masonry: masonryOpts,
            onLayout: function() {
            //  console.log('layout!' + (layoutI++) )
                forceLoad();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    html_height = $container.height();
                    $("#sidebar").height(html_height - masonryOpts.gutterWidth);
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    };
    // start up isotope with default settings
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        reLayout();
        $window.smartresize( reLayout );
    });
});
```

HTML (can be added anywhere):

```
<span id="switch"></span>
```

CSS (I don't think the media queries part is mandatory since we set this up in jquery):

```
#switch {
    display: none;
}
/**** Media queries ****/
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #switch:after {
        content: attr(data-content) "small";
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    #switch:after {
        content: attr(data-content) "medium";
    }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #switch:after {
        content: attr(data-content) "big";
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #switch:after {
        content: attr(data-content) "bigger";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems IE8 `currentStyle` object does not carry information about the `content` css property, I tested it in your webpage printing all `currentStyle` info like so:

```
for(var i in document.body.currentStyle) {
      console.log(i + ' : ' + document.body.currentStyle[i] );
}
```

and the `content` property is not present, that is why `getPropertyValue()` returns `null` in your following line:

```
var mediaQueryId = getComputedStyle( document.body, ':after' ).getPropertyValue('content');
```

and in the next line it calls `.replace()` on that `null` object and hence the error you are getting.

You need to get the `content` value some other way, currently you are printing if after body with `body:after` css, I don't know why you do that, you could try to print it to an invisible element inside your body, and later retrieve it from there.. like so:

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #hid:after {
        content: 'bigger';
    }
...
...
```

your `#hid` element could be anywhere in your page like:

```
<span id="hid" style="display:none"></span>
```

and then your `reLayout()` function would retrieve it like so:

```
function reLayout(){
// getComputedStyle is used here
            var mediaQueryId = $('#hid').html();
            // fix for firefox, remove double quotes
            var mediaQueryId = mediaQueryId.replace( /"/g, '' );
...
...
```

so doing this way you don't need your IE fix at all, which anyway does not work for the `content` property.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. After testing it seems that var mediaQueryId = $('#hid').html(); is unable to catch the content value. I am using $('#switch').html(); ... Maybe it's because the content is not actually in the html but added by CSS? Is there another way to catch it?

Comment: @Gab I'm glad you finally solved it, consider upvote my answer (up arrow) if it was helpful for you :-)